# Month specific query Mongodb and laravel

Tags: mysql, mongodb, laravel-5

I'm working with `laravel molequent` for `mongoDb` and I want to write a query which compares the current month between two dates.
Suppose I have `start_date` and `end_date`, if I write query in mysql it will be:

```
select * from table where month(curdate()) between month(start_date) and month(end_date) ;
```

Now I have to write this query in mongoDb with laravel query builder.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the aggregation framework to get the results. Consider running the following pipeline in mongo shell as demonstration of the concept, you would of course need to replace the dummy fields with
the actual fields:

```
var now = new Date(),
    currentMonth = now.getMonth()+1,
    pipeline = [
        {
            "$project": {
                "field1": 1,
                "field2": 1,
                "start_date": 1,
                "end_date": 1,
                "start_month": { "$month": "$start_date" },
                "end_month": { "$month": "$end_date" }
            }
        },
        {
            "$match": {
                "start_month": { "$lte": currentMonth },
                "end_month": { "$gte": currentMonth }
            }
        }
    ];

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

---

You can then access the underlying raw MongoDB collection in order to use the aggregation framework API:

```
$currentMonth = date("m");
$result = DB::collection('collectionName')->raw(function($collection) {
    return $collection->aggregate(array(
        array(
            "$project"=> array(
                "field1" => 1,
                "field2" => 1,
                "start_date" => 1,
                "end_date" => 1,
                "start_month" => array( "$month" => "$start_date" ),
                "end_month" => array( "$month" => "$end_date" )
            )
        ),
        array(
            "$match"=> array(
                "start_month" => array( "$lte" => $currentMonth ),
                "end_month" => array( "$gte" => $currentMonth )
            )
        )  
    ));
});
```